# BigDecimal divide returning wrong result for some calculations

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have read a few questions about flaoting point numbers and their math. To me it looks like the issues only happen at greater scales (i.e. 10+ decimals). Now my issue happens at 2 decimals already and its quite big off in a few cases:

Following code:

```
System.out.println(
        String.format("%.2f", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.8).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.87), 2).doubleValue()));
System.out.println(
        String.format("%.2f", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.41).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.73), 2).doubleValue()));
```

generates this output respectively:

```
0.80
0.89
```

If I perform the calculations by hand (using google calculations), I get these results:

```
0.72351421188
0.88278388278
```

for the first calculations the results are really big (~0.08 off) while for the second one its very low (~0.01 off).

**Is there some sane explanation as to why thie first result is that big? Or any way to get the right result using `BigDecimal`?**

Note that

```
System.out.println(2.8/3.87);
```

actually returns the right result (0.7235142118863048).

Please also note that the `String.format` stuff is only used to check if the result was changed by it which is not the case. `BigDecimal.valueOf(2.8).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.87), 2).doubleValue()` yields exactly the same result.

Comment: Try this `System.out.println(
          String.format("%.2f", new BigDecimal(2.8).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.87), 2).doubleValue()));
`

Comment: Okay, this got me the correct result. Could you explain the difference as to why that makes a difference?

Comment: Just to make sure that it's not the `double` values you're passing to `BigDecimal`, try the `String`-based instantiation.

Comment: @Lothar I have no control over instantiation of the `BigDecimals`, I can only work with them. Though `String.format("%.2f", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.8));` prints the exact value: 2.80

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Not sure, looked at the code, and does have quite a few fields which may be affected by this `static` use

Comment: I did some more tests and found that using `BigDecimal.valueOf(2.79)` results in `0.73`. Though I still don't have an explanation for this. I am now resorting to creating temporary `BigDecimal` objects using `new BigDecimal(oldDeciaml.doubleValue());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the wrong `BigDecimal#divide` for your rounding to 2 decimals. Here are the available arguments for the `BigDecimal#divide` methods:

- `divide(BigDecimal divisor)`
- `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int roundingMode)`
- `divide(BigDecimal divisor, MathContext mc)`
- `divide(BigDecimal divisor, RoundingMode roundingMode)`
- `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, int roundingMode)`
- `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)`

Since you're using a `divide` with a `BigDecimal` and `int` argument, it therefore uses the `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int roundingMode)`, where your `2` is the rounding mode and **NOT** the scale. In this case, `2` is actually `ROUND_CEILING`, and scale is unspecified.

Instead, you'll have to use either the `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, int roundingMode)` or `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)`. So change your calls to:

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.8).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.87), 2, 
  BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.41).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.73), 2, 
  BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

(Feel free to use a rounding mode other than `ROUND_HALF_UP`.)

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##nZBPT8JAEMXv/RQTTtTAEgoJBE4qMR5UjKQnY8i6u9Kt@6fpTqvG8NnrUA96EFBPk8z75b03k/Oa93P53DTaFr5EyGnBLMeMncwjYXgIcM21e48AiurRaAEBOdKovZZgSequsNRuc/8APN5hAKu3gMoyXyErSELjup00EAPSk4cCwY2oDNl4F@BFY0YolL5ykqAZdOL5Pp@ETQcjNp0cIsbDQcImo/0IKUd6nunNQgltuQGpay1V25I@gdm5d6hesf@rul8@rOamUsun3QUx@zT9SW6P60HS@9aB3S3Tm8X68vTqYp3exn@MGw8P5bWf@m9eq2yjbdN8AA)

I'm not sure what scale it uses by default, but the `ROUND_CEILING` you've specified with your `2` caused the issues in your calculations.

---

As for the mentioned comments, there are three possible ways to create the `BigDecimal` with the specified values:

- `BigDecimal.valueOf(2.8)`
- `new BigDecimal(2.8)`
- `new BigDecimal("2.8")`

The `new BigDecimal(2.8)` still gives floating point errors, so I would advice to use either `BigDecimal.valueOf(2.8)` as you already did, or the String constructor `new BigDecimal("2.8")`.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##lZBPC4JAEMXvforBkxbtoVPkLaJbdPAYHSZdbW3XFR2NCD@77WYQVAqeBua995s/GTa4yOJr1wlV6JIgMw2mkC5sFjiRxKqCPYr84QAU9VmKCCpCMqXRIgZlJC@kUuTp8QToWxtAeK@IK6ZrYoWRSOaeu9Umzdfgzpds5QeDvp3USG9bMuLbiHTLI6FQsgZlzQ@JDf12PTtuhJPzG3xSXvxa07esL2UaJ7FnDGCSCZz@t/9AriG5Pal12q57Ag)

This is all a bit irrelevant for your rounding issues however, since using the correct `divide` method will give the correct results regardless of the `BigDecimal` initialization you've used:

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##rZFBS8MwGIbv/RUfASHR7hPqweFOShEP6sSxk8r4bNKZmqRlTSsi@@012xDKqMODp0Ce933zQApqaVTI967TtipXHopwgZb8Gx5PosxQXcMdafcVAVTNq9EZ1J58ONpSS7AB8Zlfabd8egESmxjA7LP2ymLZeKwC8jlnaRnKaiR1q6W6gCNM8mfH4gTHp2c4PheTwaJxnF3pZaoybclgS6ZR05zL7ZiAnzV2MhAK0wJ3CT6At6/GkMTQg4/T@X26uLm8vV7MH8QBKac@er0Bob1AX2YP/avI7isOiLBgwn5TYRsX9heZdbTuum8)

Comment: So basically the issue is the unspecified/too low scale for the initial `BigDecimal`. `2.80` results in a scale of `1` while it should be `2` in this case. `2.81` results in a scale of `2` which is correct as we have 2 decimals

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Ah, you're indeed right about the default scaling; scale `1` for `2.8` and scale `2` for `3.87`, so the result is scale `1` as well; which results in `0.8` in combination with your `ROUND_CEILING`. The main issue is the usage of the wrong `divide` method, but you're indeed right that the scale is based on the double-value you've used. With `new BigDecimal("2.80")` instead of `BigDecimal.valueOf(2.8)`, the results would have been different as well indeed.

Comment: And that all is only because `Double.toString(2.80)` returns `2.8` instead of `2.80`. the chosen `divide` method would work fine if the scaling oculd be applied properly, which is not the case as seen throughout this Q/A

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you do realise that the double literal value 2.80 is exactly the same, identical and indistinguishable value as 2.8, don't you? The compiler sees no difference whatsoever between the two.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `BigDecimal.valueOf(2.8)` simply calls `new BigDecimal(Double.toString(2.8))`, so you might as well just call `new BigDecimal("2.8")` directly.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I know; I personally use `new BigDecimal(String)` in most cases when I use BigDecimals/BigIntegers. Just figured I'd add all three variations on how to instantiate a BigDecimal value for completeness, regardless of how it's internally done.

Comment: By the way, I strongly recommend using the `RoundingMode` enum instead of the int constants. For example, in `BigDecimal.valueOf(x).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(y),2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)` if you mistakenly swap the decimal places argument (e.g. 2) and the rounding mode argument, you will get the wrong results at runtime. But if you use the RoundingMode enum, you will get a compilation error instead. Consider the int rounding modes as legacy (pre-Java 1.6).